# Cmd copies twice some files to a destination

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd, copy

> `C:\My\Download\Location` = directory where there is this folder called 
>   `Naruto`, and inside `Naruto` there's `Naruto.mkv`
>
> `C:\My\Other\Location` = default download location where I want `Naruto`
>   folder moved, with inside `Naruto.mkv`

This is the command I ran:

```
FOR /R C:\My\Download\Location %f IN (.) DO robocopy "%f" "C:\My\Other\Location" /S
```

This command looks for a folder `(.)` in `C:\My\Download\Location` (`%f` is the folder) and will copy it with inside `Naruto.mkv` in `C:\My\Other\Location`

The problem is that in `C:\My\Other\Location` there's even `Naruto.mkv`, when it should be only in the folder `Naruto`

So, after the command `FOR /R C:\My\Download\Location %f IN (.) DO robocopy "%f" "C:\My\Other\Location" /S`, I'm in this state:

> `C:\My\Other\Location\Naruto\Naruto.mkv`
>
> `C:\My\Other\Location\Naruto.mkv` (this shouldn't exist)

Why does it copy even `Naruto.mkv`?

And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved doing this:

```
cd C:\My\Download\Location
FOR /R C:\My\Download\Location %f IN (.) DO move "%f" "C:\My\Other\Location"
```